# Freelancer to Entrepreneur

Tags: working-from-home, portfolio

I am a part time freelancer since last 4 years along with full-time job. Sometimes it feels like being your own boss and sometimes subcontracting the work gives me pleasure of being an investor where money works for you while you're sleeping.

Reaping the benefits of such experience, I consider myself to start my own business. Is it good thinking or just vague imagination? How running a startup is different from being freelancer?

Answer (score 3):

Having done both:

Startup is to freelancing like - take your administrative overhead and multiply by 100. Also take your responsibility and your worries and multiply by 100.

- If you are good at your job, stay freelancer.
- If you are good at finding people who are good at their job, start a company.

Comment: Very calculated answer...

Comment: @Daniel, if a freelancer gets ill, or a contractor goes on holidays, they don't earn any money. However as an entrepreneur, your business keeps running and billing. All you have to do is delegating tasks and keep an eye. As a freelancer, you're basically trading life for money. But at the end of day you can't go to the supermarket and buy life.

Comment: I want to see that startup where the founder can go on holiday in the startup-years!
As a Freelancer, if your sick and holiday time is not factored in, your are doing something seriously wrong. You should find an employment.
And **NO** you are not trading life for money, you are trading your time for money - same as any employee would, just with a slightly different economic approach.

Comment: Ah the ... keep running and billing: its actually the return of investment (time=money). Startup is kind of a high-risk, high-yield investment. It can as well bankrupt you, especially if you are not skilled in this kind of "investment"

Comment: @Daniel, as a contractor in the UK never got any money when sick. Time is life, because time is not a renewable resource. My bosses were at home with their families or travelling and come to the office once a week. When a limited company is declared bankrupt, it is the company that is bankrupt and not the persons behind the business. My savings are safe as I'm not liable for the company's debts.

Comment: As a freelancer your rate should be high enough to factor in Holidays and shorter sick times. For longer sick times you should have an insurance, which has also be covered by your rate. If you do not collect this money from you customers, you are hurting yourself financially and making dumping prices. You are not fit as a business man, your calculation is off. You should seek normal employment, where somebody else does this calcualtion for you!

Comment: A limited Company does not run on air, it takes time and money (probably your personal saving) to get it started. This time and money is lost when you bankrupt. An if you do something wrong they can even still get to your personal savings through coourt.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for your advices but as I've mentioned before I do have my own limited company and here in the UK this costs nothing. My daily rate are not "dump prices", I charge £350+VAT or £500 inside IR35. I see lots of assumptions about me in your comments and not surprisingly all were wrong. Never heard about a contractor being paid when sick in the UK, though this may be different in your country. I expect not to get another permanent position in my life, I hate them and my CV is not a good fit for a perm. Anyway, thanks for your advices.

Comment: @derloopkat: Just wantet to clarify I was not making any assumptions about you, just talking about freelancing vs entrepreneur in general here. And no you dont get paid while you are sick as freelancer. You should earn enough to pay youself or pay for sick-insurance while you are working. Thats part of why a freelancer has earn more per hour than an employee.